# [Bug in ROS | Solved] Extending SimpleActionServer/-Client to allow REJECTING goals

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, actionlib, simpleactionclient, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: This is a known bug, refer to [my comment in this bug tracker on Github](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/46#issuecomment-234568950) for a possible solution and more details. More information can also be found in my accepted answer below.

Hi folks,

I am trying to **extend the functionality** of the [`SimpleActionServer`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionServer.html) / -[`Client`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html) classes **to allow rejecting new goals** if (and only if) there are currently none being processed. That is, I would like to replace/disable the `PENDING` [state](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleClientGoalState.html#a91066f14351d31404a2179da02c518a0) logically in a sense that when there is currently an `ACTIVE` goal, it will not be preempted and the very recently received goal will automatically be rejected by the server. In contrast, once a new goal is received and there is no goal being currently processed, the server should accept the new goal. However, I would like to retain the ability to cancel/abort a goal (both by the client and the server) just in case this matters.

To achieve this, I've modified the [actionlib tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib/Tutorials) (namely [1](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29), [2](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient), [3](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28GoalCallbackMethod%29), and [4](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient%28Threaded%29)). You can find my modified `learning_actionlib` package for [**download here**](https://depot.tu-dortmund.de/6ykyy). Modifications are basically in the `goalCallback()` function, simply search for `CHANGED` in `order_action_server_imp.h`. You can compile it in any Indigo/Jade/Kinetic workspace and run it (from your `catkin_ws` dir) using

```
roslaunch src/learning_actionlib/launch/test.launch
```

or

```
roslaunch src/learning_actionlib/launch/test_avg.launch
```

The **problem** with that code **is as follows**: When one of the above launchfiles is started, a single server and multiple clients are being launched at the 'same' time (-> workload creation). On my slower machine (i7 4600U, VMware player), it regularily happens that 1 or more clients incorrectly timeout while one client always (correctly) returns `SUCCEEDED` and all the others correctly report `REJECTED`. However, I would assume that exactly one client succeeds and **all** others get rejected. It seems that the server correctly publishes the `REJECTED` states as the following (`DEBUG`) **log shows** but the clients don't get these information: http://pastebin.com/m9k5xniD . In particular and according to that log, the server correctly receives all goals, only processes the first (lines 7-12) and rejects new ones (lines 17, 23, 29) -> 4 clients.
Note that it doesn't matter if `test.launch` or `test_avg.launch` is used, both have the same problem. I guess the problem is related to spinning/multithreading (and parallel code execution in general as this only rarely happens on my fast 12-core machine). Also, if I decrease the #cores in my VM, the probability of occurrence increases. Thus, if you don't have the problem, you may need to restart the launchfiles a few times or increase the number of clients.

Please also note that I am occasionally get a

> double free or corruption

(related to a `std::vector::push_back` used inside a `boost::mutex`) and

> average_server:
> /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:110:
> void boost::recursive_mutex::lock():
> Assertion `!pthread_mutex_lock(&m)'
> failed.

error when terminating roslaunch by Ctrl+C. Not sure if this is related. In general, I am not sure if my code modifications (again, see `order_action_server_imp.h`, w.r.t. rejecting new goals) are correct.

Moreover, is it safe to execute long running (> min) code in a `execute_callback` provided by the actionlib? I am unsure whether this causes the wired behavior because new callbacks are probably not (?) serviced.

If you have any question or need further information, please let me know. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks for your time and reading all this!

EDIT: For testing, I've removed all  mutexes and condition variables from the server and the problem still happens. Thus, it may not be related to sync. ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240056/%5Bbug-in-ros-%7C-solved%5D-extending-simpleactionserver/-client-to-allow-rejecting-goals/) by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-06-30**:\

> You can find my modified `learning_actionlib` package for **download here**.

The link is dead, is the code still up anywhere?

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2021-07-02**:
No, sorry. Unfortunately, I don't have the code anymore since I re-installed that computer. :-(

If I find a copy though, I will let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Interestingly, I found the solution: presumably, it's a **bug** (?) **in ROS** (can confirm it for **Indigo** and **Kinetic**)!

*The short story:* the `status_sub_`, `feedback_sub_`, and `result_sub_` subscriptions in `/opt/$ROS_DIST/include/actionlib/client/action_client.h@initClient()` are created with a **queue size of only 1**. This simply causes **messages to get lost.**

I can't think of any reason why to set a queue size of 1. IMHO, this may even cause other wired problems with high loads / less ressources between server/clients.

*The long story:* I've done the following things to track down the problem to its actual origin.

- The debug output of the server suggests that it correctly sends the `REJECTED` states and its associated result (cf. link above). To verify this, I've used `rostopic echo /fibonacci/result` to check whether I receive 1 `SUCCEEDED` and `N-1` `REJECTED` result msgs (given `N` clients).
- As this was the case, I've subscribed to `/fibonacci/result` in the client to check whether these msgs also arrive at the client. (Note that all messages from all clients arrive at each client.) Interestingly, the msgs arrive only if I set the queue size to some large value (not 1). Setting it to 1 (like in `action_client.h`, see the short story above) causes messages to get lost.
- Then I temporarily modified the queue sizes in `/opt/$ROS_DIST/include/actionlib/client/action_client.h@initClient()` and set them to 1000, and voila: after recompiling, all `REJECTED` states are received correctly and none of my clients timed out.
- Summary: (simple / my) server code is correct, (simple / my) client code should be correct, ROS' `ActionClient<T>` impl. has a bug

Glad to **receive some comments/feedback on this**. If it's a bug, it should be fixed in the official sources. Can anyone confirm this (ideally, one of the ROS maintainer/developers)?

---

Originally posted by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) with karma: 100 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-22**:
If you really feel this is a bug (which I feel technically isn't correct, as a queue size of 1 is valid, and it may just be that the rationale for it is unclear), I suggest you open an issue on the [tracker](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues).

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2016-07-22**:
Thanks for pointing me to that site!  It is obviously a known bug so that I've added a comment and reference to this post (see https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/46#issuecomment-234568950 ). Can you accept my answer as the correct one, please? I am not having enough reputation yet.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-22**:
It'd be nice if you could edit your answer to insert an *update* section at the top pointing users to the issue on the github tracker, so they don't have to scroll down and read everything. I'll give you some additional karma, so you can accept your own answer.

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2016-07-22**:
Thanks, all done! ;-)